# A switch expression and an operator error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two lines of code which are giving me errors:

```
private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    switch (combobox1.SelectedValue)
                {
                    case 0:
                        var item = items.Where(category => category.CategoryIndex == 0);

                        foreach (var i in item)
                        {
                            listbox.Items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = i.CategoryIndex, ItemDesc = i.ItemDesc, ItemName = i.ItemName });
                        }
                        break;


                    case 1:
                        item = items.Where(category => category.CategoryIndex == 1);

                        foreach (var i in item)
                        {
                            listbox.Items.Add(new Items { CategoryIndex = i.CategoryIndex, ItemDesc = i.ItemDesc, ItemName = i.ItemName });
                        }
                        break;
```

Heres the second :

```
 private void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = items.Where(category => category.CategoryIndex == listbox.SelectedValue && (itemName => itemName.ItemName == listbox.SelectedItem.ToString()));

            listbox.Text = item.ItemName;
            desrciption_label.Text = item.ItemDesc;     
        }
```

The error in the first code is at

```
switch (combobox.SelectedValue)
```

The error states that:

> A switch expression or case label must be bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type_

The error in the second code is at

```
category.CategoryIndex == listbox.SelectedValue
```

This error states that:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object'

How to fix these?

**NOTE**: There is more *a lot* code to this, since it's so big I'm leaving it out but if the previous code is needed, please inform me of this

Comment: you can't use a lamba in a boolean expression like that

Comment: Should you be using `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedValue`?

Comment: `SelectedValue` is of type object - what about [`SelectedIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, you will need to cast that `combobox.SelectedValue` to something else, i.e.

```
int choice = (int)combobox.SelectedValue;
```

depending on whatever type of thing `SelectedValue` is.

This is because `combobox.SelectedValue` is an `object`, so you need to cast it to your data type. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on ComboBox properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
[BrowsableAttribute(false)]
[BindableAttribute(true)]
public ***object*** SelectedValue { get; set; }`
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) for more.

You are passing in an `object` to the switch, but the cases are integers. You need to resolve that selected value to an integer. Perhaps a straight cast will work but I don't know what is in that combobox.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are self-explanatory.
The first comes from `SelectedValue` returning an `Object`, which is not allowed in a `switch`-statement. You should most likely use `SelectedIndex`.
Second means that you can't compare `int` with `Object`.
`CategoryIndex` is an `int`, and you can't compare it to `SelectedValue`, which is an object, like in the first case. Again using `SelectedIndex` should fix it.
If the `SelectedValue` is in fact the property you should be using (after databinding for example), cast the object to an int to get proper types (or parse).